# How do you remove/add classes for a lot of buttons(or any DOM elements) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a lot of buttons that I'd like to remove/add classes to. Mainly, if they've been selected, I'd like to add a 'selected' class to them. I don't want to create 10 different state variables and 10 different handlers to set the state in order to change the class on each button. Is there a different way to do this? Currently, the way I'm doing it is:

```
var button1Class = ClassNames({'selected': this.state.button1Selected})
<button className={button1Class} onClick={this.handleButton1Clicked} />

handleButton1Clicked: function() {
  this.setState({
     button1Selected: !this.state.button1Selected
   });
}
```

.
.
.
(buttons 2 - 9)

```
var button10Class = ClassNames({'selected': this.state.button10Selected})
<button className={button10Class} onClick={this.handleButton10Clicked} />

handleButton10Clicked: function() {
  this.setState({
     button10Selected: !this.state.button10Selected
   });
}
```

This seems way too verbose, and seems wrong. But I can't figure out any other way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to create your own button component with its own state?

Comment: Ended up going with this (creating a separate component) -thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a few things to make your code a bit more DRY.  We can try to pull some common functionality into a more generic function, as well as loop where needed.

First, you can set up a button handler that takes a parameter:

```
handleButtonClick: function(index) {
    var property = 'button'+index+'Selected';
    var newState = {};
    newState[property] = !this.state[property];
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Then, loop during your render, accessing properties dynamically:

```
var buttons = [];
for ( var i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
    var className = ClassNames({
        'selected': this.state['button'+i+'Selected']
    });
    buttons.push((
        <button className={className} onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this, i)} />
    ));
}
```

Comment: Cool! This is a cool solution, thank you! and it definitely will work. I ended up creating a separate component as per @Road's suggestion for the buttons and made them have their own state, figured it'd be easier to manage that way.